# Move Appointment to a different calendar automatically

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I set up 2 email addresses in Outlook 2016:

- primary email address
- secondary email address

furthermore, I have different calendars

- standard calendar
- private calendar
- work calendar

Is it possible to configure Outlook 2016 in such a way, that appointments from my primary email address are automatically added to the work calendar, and invitations from my secondary email address are automatically added to my private calendar?